# protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. does not compile on windows

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, proto

I was trying to install TensorFlow object detection API and it requires the installation of protobuf so I downloaded versions: 3.4.0, 3.14.0 , 3.9.0 and I copied the protoc.exe to the models/research folder then write this line on anaconda Commandline (protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.) and I made sure that I am working within the directory of models research and i got nothing as shown in the image [Image after running protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhvL6.png) 
this happened on all the versions of protobuf that I tried to work with.
I am working on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

There is no output from the protoc command, you can follow along with the next steps.